# Post analysis of conditional logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, stata, diagnostic

I have a conditional logistic regression model with significant sample size (well into five figures of groups and six figures worth of observations) and, overall, excellent outcomes in predicting future events. However, every once in a while, the forecast is way off.

What are some strategies, techniques or approaches used to dive deep into these models after the fact? In other words, in knowing the subject matter I can say to myself, "Something isn't captured here, the model is way off." But, trying to "reverse engineer" the model and its output... I'm struggling with that.

I'm an "amateur" and purely a hobbyist when it comes to statistics. For the most part, everything is self taught with the exception of basic stuff learned in college. So I apologize if this sounds ridiculous!

Comment: Is the outcome fairly rare? Also, what does it mean for the forecast to be way off?

Comment: It's forecasting horse races and if it models 40 races per day around 3-4, on average, are way off. It's producing winning probabilities and thus a horse might be given a 5% when in reality, through institutional knowledge and other metrics, the number should be closer to say 25%.

Comment: You need to tell us more! What kind of variables did you use, (categorical or numerical?), how many variables, did you make some plots? (Show us some!). Without some of this informatio0n not much can be said, other than: plot, plot, plot